# unable to invoke bound script from sheets on iPad

Tags: google-apps-script, mobile, google-sheets

Unable to manually invoke bound script in Google sheet when accessing from iPad using Sheets app

I created a bound script in a Google spreadsheet that I want to access from different devices. The main sheet contains raw data. The script summarizes the raw data and puts the results in a second sheet. I created custom menu (ui.createMenu) to allow the user to select one of several extract options.

This worked fine when I load the spreadsheet in Chrome on a PC but the custom menu doesn’t show when you open the spreadsheet in the Sheets app on an iPad.  So I tried adding a Dashboard sheet with several buttons linked to the functions for the different extract options.  Again this works fine on a PC, but when I open the Dashboard sheet on my iPad and tap one of the buttons it acts like I’m trying to edit the sheet instead of running the script.

Comment: Running scripts on mobiles is not supported as far as I know.  You might be able to accomplish what you need using a WebApp.

Comment: [Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script+mobile)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't possible to edit the UI elements in mobile versions of Sheets, and [add-ons are not available for iPhone and iPad](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2942256?co=GENIE.Platform%3DiOS&hl=en&oco=0) so a workaround can't be done this way either.

For mobile sheets I use the functionality of `onEdit(e)` and the event object to workaround this:

I freeze the first row of the sheet so that it's always viewable, with a dropdown menu in B1 like so:

[image]

My Apps Script code then has validation in the `onEdit(e)` trigger which first checks to see if the edit has been made in the cell `B1`, and executes the code I need it to based on the selection:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getA1Notation !== 'B1'){
    return;
  }
  else{
    var selectedFunction = e.range.getValue();

    if (selectedFunction == 'myFunction()'){
      myFunction();
    }
    else if (selectedFunction == 'otherFunction()'){
      otherFunction();
    }
    else if (selectedFunction == 'thirdFunction()'){
      thirdFunction();
    }
  }
}

function myFunction(){
  // my code
}
function otherFunction(){
  // other code
}
function thirdFunction(){
  // third code
}
```

I know it's not a perfect solution but I hope that it could be useful for your case.

Answer (score 0):

I like R.G.'s solution since the only alternative I've found to kick off a custom menu item is creating a "button" drawing and attaching a function trigger to it. (I found the drawing part a little difficult to control inside a cell.)

Below is my adaption of R.G.'s solution which I found worked well in a situation where there already were other onEdit(e) routines. In this example the dropdown is in B2

```
// IOS/ANDROID MENU ROUTINE
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
var sheetNameToWatch = "Entry sheet";
var columnNumberToWatch = 2;
var rowNumberToWatch = 1; 
var menuItem1 = "Update";
var menuItem2 = "Clear Staging";
var range = sheet.getActiveCell();

if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getRow() == rowNumberToWatch && range.getValue() == menuItem1) {
       [your_function_no_1]();
       }
else if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getRow() == rowNumberToWatch && range.getValue() == menuItem2) {
       [your_function_no_2]();
  }
```